# Angular, setInterval cause component to non-stop update its UI

Tags: angular

I need to have a setInterval in one of my child components to check one of my DIV height. Problem is I found out that this setInterval cause my component UI non-stop update itself. Event the parent component also non-stop update itself.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-comp',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let num of [1,2,3]">
        {{ print(num) }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
class TestComponent {
  private attr: Date;
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {}, 1000)
  }
  print(num) {
    return num + ' ' + new Date();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let num of [1,2,3,4]">{{ test(num) }}</li>
      </ul>
      <app-test-comp></app-test-comp>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  test(num) {
    return num + ' ' + new Date()
  }
}
```

[PlunkerLink](https://plnkr.co/edit/U8irvwnhJVmObP6A0FEC?p=preview)

Refer to plunker link above, it clearly shows that root component and its child component keep on updating its UI. If I remove that setInterval in app.ts line 18, it will behave as normal.

I wish to know what causes the non-stop update UI problem and how to prevent that.

Comment: SetInterval is monkeypatched to mark the component for dirty checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async methods like `setInterval` are monkey patched by `zone.js`, a library used by angular to 
update the view after model has changed. Monkey patching means extending functionality of a method.
So whenever the `setInterval` is called, the angular change detection is fired to update the view.

You can run your code outside of angular to avoid running change detection:

```
constructor(
    private zone: NgZone
) {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        setInterval(() => {}, 1000)
    })
}
```

I have updated your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/u6QOzU8BXfNk3UAMcRIO) with above example

Answer (score 2):

Angular depends on `zone.js` and zone monkey patches native methods like `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, therefore if you're using `setInterval` you're actually using the patched version, therefore angular is updating the UI.

To prevent this angular has a service called [**NgZone**](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) which implements a way to run methods outside the angular zone.

For example:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { 
  this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    setInterval(() => {}, 1000); // this runs outside of the angular zone
    this._zone.run(() => {
      // this runs inside the angular zone
    });

  });
}
```

A more detailed explanation about zones in angular can be found in this [**article**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html).