# setInterval() inside Angular app causes infinite UI re-render

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, setinterval

Below I have an oversimplified countdown timer that I'm using in my Angular 9 app. The actual countdown timer shows a 'days, hours, minutes, seconds' countdown and should update every second.

The countdown timer is within its own component and as it's inside its own component I'd expect when the timer's template updates only the component would update. However, I'm finding that the countdown's parent page is also re-rendering.

I am aware that setInterval has been ['monkey patched' by zone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261096/angular-setinterval-cause-component-to-non-stop-update-its-ui) however I can't find a way of keeping the reactivity of the countdown timer.

Any recommendations would be appreciated

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown',
  template: `<h2>{{counter}}</h2>`
})
export class CountdownComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  counter = 0
  interval;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startCountDown();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  startCountDown() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
    },1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will be best solution but have you tried stopping the auto angular change detection using detach() of the ChangeDetectorRef and then calling detectChanges() inside the setInterval. But once you detach u will have to update all changes manually which might not satisfy your use case

Answer (score 1):

You can run interval outside of Angular zone and then detect changes manually:

```
  startCountDown() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter++;
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); 
      },1000)
    });
  }
```

But in this concrete case I would probably update value using plain Javascript:

```
  startCountDown() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter++;
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = this.counter;
      },1000)
    });
  }
```